# Databricks error abfss://<stoarage-account>.dfs.core.windows.net has invalid authority

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-data-lake-gen2

While accessing Azure data lake container with Databricks this error shows up, I have not made any changes, below are the steps that I followed. not sure why it is not working same steps used to work earlier

1. Created Storage account
2. Create Databricks resource
3. added some data into the storage
4. And tried accessing storage data using below spark command.

   spark.conf.set(
   "fs.azure.account.key..dfs.core.windows.net",
   dbutils.secrets.get(scope="", key=""))

not sure why I am getting below error,
[image]

Comment: what are you using for authentication SAS or Access key?

Comment: I tried both but none of them worked. I got same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> abfss://.dfs.core.windows.net has invalid authority

**The error you are getting is because you are using wrong end points.
When you use ABFSS the correct format of storage account URL is as below**

```
abfss://containername@storageaccountname.dfs.core.windows.net/
```

[image]